# Loop through current row cells and stop on next non zero value - leave that as active cell

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I have a file with very long rows of data. They are formulae and many of the results are zero values.
I would like a macro that will loop through the active row and stop at the next non-zero value cell, leaving that as the active cell.

This will save time scrolling through looking manually for the non-zeros and also avoid the human error of missing them as you scroll through.

I think (in pseudo code) I want something along the lines of:

```
For active cell To end of row

If value is zero then active cell x+1

Next

End if

End
```

I can't write VBA myself, just vaguely understand what it is doing by reading it and can copy and modify similar coding but I can't find anything close enough for this.
I haven't a clue how to declare the variables etc. at the top either.

I would really really appreciate some help with this. I have been struggling with it for months and I think it should probably be quite simple.

Comment: You have been struggling with it for months, so presumably you studied enough VBA to make an attempt at this?

Comment: Unfortunately my job has nothing to do with VBA so I can't take up time to learn it. This is just something that I think would really help other people in the company in using this tool. I have asked to be sent on a course but that hasn't happened.
Would you be able to help me?

Comment: So in what sense have you been "struggling with it for months"? Anyway, you could pick up a copy of the `Excel VBA for Dummies` book, which is very good, and work through it in your spare time if the subject interests you.

Comment: I have been looking for similar codes and trying to write things and nothing has worked cause I don't have the proper knowledge and haven't found an example similar enough.
The subject doesn't really interest me so much, this is the only macro that I would like to write. 
I thought that people were helpful on these forums so I was hoping someone could help. I'm pretty sure for someone fluent in VBA this would be very simple and not take much of their time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is going to be closed due to being too broad, because it is.
However, here is a short snippet i hope will help you and maybe others who wil google this issue in the future:

```
Public Sub StackOverflowExample()
    Dim LastColumnNumber As Integer
    'get the number of the last column with data in row of the currently selected cell
    'we dont want to go through the entire row when data ends, only until the last cell with data
    LastColumnNumber = ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    'i is our iteration variable, will go from the number of the currently selected cell
    'to the number of the last column with data. we start from the next cell each time
    'otherwise the macro wont work if the selected cell has a non 0 value
    For i = ActiveCell.Column + 1 To LastColumnNumber
        'check if the value of cell with column number i on the current row is not 0
        'Note: if you do a number comparison, empty cells' values will count as 0 as well
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i) <> 0 Then
            'select the found cell, scroll the sheet to it and exit the FOR loop
            ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i).Select
            Application.Goto ActiveCell, True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Also, it works perfectly and I understand it and this has made my day!